# bigger than and lesser than javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a simple function that validates an ID.
the ID is supposed to be longer either 2 or 3 letters, so bigger than or equal to 2 and lesser than or equal to 3, heres what im using atm:

```
else if (pasientID.length < 2)
{
 lovligPasientID=false;
 feilmelding="Pasient ID'en er ikke lang nok.";
}

else if(pasientID.length > 3)
{
 lovligPasientID=false;
 feilmelding="Pasient ID'en er for lang.";
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: So the length of the id can either be 2 or 3?

Comment: Your signs are the wrong way round. Should be `> 2` and `< 3`. Also, add the equals. So, `>= 2` and `<= 3` [Have a look at this.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators) - But as others have said, since it can only be either 2 or 3, consider using the or operator `||`.

Comment: There should be if associated with else if.

Answer (score 0):

You can get id property by getAttribute and check length it

```js
function checkLength(button){
console.log(button.getAttribute("id"))
let len = button.getAttribute("id").length;
if (len<2){
console.log("too short")
}
if (len>3)
console.log("too long")
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="twoooo" onclick="checkLength(this)" value="button" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be made cleaner with [`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and regex.

```
/^([a-zA-Z]|[0-9]){2,3}$/g
```

This will match any 2 or 3 character alphanumeric string.

```js
let id = '5', id2 = '23', id3 ='ABC', id4 = 'ABCD';

function validate(patientID) {
  if (patientID.match(/^([a-zA-Z]|[0-9]){2,3}$/g)) {
    console.log('ok');
  }
  else { 
    console.log('not ok');
  }
};

validate(id);
validate(id2);
validate(id3);
validate(id4);
```